# Bind rabbitmq to localhost on ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to bind rabbitmq to localhost for security.
for redis i found [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-redis-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-3-%E2%80%94-binding-to-localhost). but how can i do this for rabbitmq?

Answer (score 1):

Putting the following in **/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf** will make RabbitMQ and epmd listen on only localhost:

```
export RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit@localhost
export RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
export ERL_EPMD_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
```

It takes a bit more work to configure Erlang to only use localhost for the higher numbered port (which is used for clustering nodes as far as I can tell). If you don't care about clustering and just want Rabbit to be run fully locally then you can pass Erlang a kernel option for it to only use the loopback interface.

To do so, create a new file in **/etc/rabbitmq/** - I'll call it rabbit.config. In this file we'll put the Erlang option that we need to load on run time.

```
[{kernel,[{inet_dist_use_interface,{127,0,0,1}}]}].
```

If you're using the management plugin and also want to limit that to localhost, you'll need to configure its ports separately, making the **rabbit.config** include this:

```
[
    {rabbitmq_management, [
        {listener, [{port, 15672}, {ip, "127.0.0.1"}]}
    ]},
    {kernel, [
        {inet_dist_use_interface,{127,0,0,1}}
    ]}
].
```

(Note RabbitMQ leaves epmd running when it shuts down, so if you want to block off Erlang's clustering port, you will need to restart epmd separately from Rabbit.)

Next we need to have RabbitMQ load this at startup. 
Open up **/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf** again and put the following at the top:

**export RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/rabbitmq/rabbit"**

This loads that config file when the rabbit server is started and will pass the options to Erlang.

You should now have all Erlang/RabbitMQ processes listening only on localhost!

This can be checked with

```
netstat -ntlap
```

Not that in older versions of RabbitMQ, the configuration file is **/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf**. 
However, this file has been replaced by the rabbit-env.conf file.

Comment: my /etc/rabbitmq/ is empty. should i create these files myself?